# bulk generate AWS KMS data keys

Tags: encryption, amazon-kms

I am trying to execute a batch of existing encrypted data source to use aws kms and re-encrypt every record / row of the data source with a new data key.

I'm using aws kms generateDataKey and then encrypting the data with generated key. However, this is slower and I would like to generate keys in a batch rather than individual api calls to speed it up.

Is this possible using aws kms?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an api reference for this. So I am going to mark this as No there is no such api